# Understanding unsigned 0 in C

Tags: c

I am trying to understand number representation in C.
I am working on a code segment which looks like the one below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer;

void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, int len) 
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf(" %.2x", start[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void show_int(int x) {
    show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(int));
}

void show_unsigned(short x) {
    show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(unsigned));
}
int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    int length=0;
    unsigned g=(unsigned)length;// i aslo tried with unsigned g=0 and the bytes are the same
    show_unsigned(g);
    show_int(length);
    printf("%d",g);//this prints 0
    return 0;
}
```

Here, `show_unsigned()` and `show_int()` prints the byte representations of the variables specified as arguments.For int length the byte representation is all zeroes as expected, but for unsigned g, the byte representation is `00 00 04 08`.But when I print g with a %d, I get 0(so i suppose the numeric value is interpreted as 0 )

Please could somebody explain how this is happening.

Comment: Remember: if you have a 2 gallon pitcher full of tasty lemonade, you can't pour 4 gallons out.

Comment: `typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer;` is **horrible.**

Comment: @H2CO3 Could you please tell me why that construct is horrible? I am not good with C, actually i have just about started learning it.

Comment: @user1587457 Because it obscures the code and decreases readability. I dislike pointer `typedef`s (and arbitrary integer ones too) for this exact reason. You better just stick to `const unsigned char *`, or *at most* `typedef unsigned char byte;` then `const byte *`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In:

```
void show_unsigned(short x) {
    show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(unsigned));
}
```

You declared the argument `short x` which is smaller than `int x` so you ignored some of the `00` and your print function is displaying adjacent garbage.

Comment: Not to mention that it isn't unsigned.

Comment: +1. This can be fixed by changing `sizeof(unsigned)` to `sizeof(short)`.

Comment: Also worth noting that any compiler would have caught this with the appropriate warnings enabled.

Comment: Could you tell me the appropriate warnings ? I am using Geany which i believe uses gcc -Wall -o printbytes printbytes.c

Comment: @user1587457: C's warnings for narrowing are not always very useful.  Due to integral promotion (another good concept to look up and understand) most integer expressions are `int` or `unsigned` so you would get annoying warnings all the time for things like `short x = 1 + 2`.

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing doesn't make any sense, particularly with the type conversions that you have occurring. Someone else already pointed out my point about the conversion to short

Rather than writing an absurd number of functions try doing this

```
void show_bytes( void *start, unsigned int len ) {
    unsigned char* ptr = (unsigned char *) start;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < len; ++i, ++ptr ) {
        printf( " %.2x", ptr[0] );
    }
}
```

Instead of calling as you had been just call it like:
`show_bytes( (void *)&x, sizeof(x));`

And if thats too much typing make a macro out of that. now it works for any type you come up with.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading `sizeof(unsigned)` bytes in a `short`. `short` isn't guaranteed to be the same size as `unsigned`, hence, when reading the bytes next to your short, garbage data is read.

To fix this, either pass your argument as an `unsigned`, or when using sizeof, use `sizeof(short)`.